# Emphasise an equation within align environment

Tags: align, emphasis

I would like to emphasise and so make bigger the first and the last row of this align environment. This because the two rows in the middle are of course important but not as much as the result.
I am doing a beamer presentation, hence

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
{\scriptsize
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}(n) &= \int_\mathbb{R} \exp\{-n g(y)\} dy\\ 
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left\{-n\left[\tilde{g} + \frac{1}{2}(y-\tilde{y})^{2} \tilde{g}^{\prime \prime} + \frac{1}{6}(y - \tilde{y})^3 \tilde{g}^{\prime \prime \prime} + \frac{1}{24}(y - \tilde{y})^4 \tilde{g}^{I V} + O((y-\tilde{y})^{5})\right]\right\} d y \\ 
&= \exp\{-n \tilde{g}\} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left\{-\frac{n}{2}(y-\tilde{y})^{2} \tilde{g}^{\prime \prime} - \frac{n}{6}(y - \tilde{y})^3 \tilde{g}^{\prime \prime \prime} - \frac{n}{24}(y - \tilde{y})^4 \tilde{g}^{I V}+ nO(y-\tilde{y})^{5}\right\} d y \\ 
&=\frac{\exp\{-n \tilde{g}\} \sqrt{2 \pi}}{\sqrt{n \tilde{g}^{\prime \prime}}}\left\{1-\frac{1}{8} \frac{\tilde{g}^{IV}}{n(\tilde{g}^{\prime \prime})^2} + \frac{5}{24n} \frac{(\tilde{g}^{\prime \prime \prime})^2}{(\tilde{g}^{\prime \prime})^3} + O (n^{-2})\right\},
\end{align*}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Can somebody help please?

Comment: It will look bad to change size. Have you considered changing colors instead. I think there is `\mathcolor` if you have an updated installation.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I actually need to change size.

Comment: Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd not do it: if the calculations aren't important in the presentation, just omit them. Your audience will not have the time to parse those long formulas, even less to follow the steps.

Anyway, here's how you could do it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\REDUCE}[1]{\mbox{\tiny$\displaystyle#1$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}(n) &= \int_{\RR} \exp\{-n g(y)\} \, dy\\[2ex]
&= \REDUCE{
 \int_{\RR} \exp \left\{
   -n\left[
     \tilde{g} + \frac{1}{2}(y-\tilde{y})^{2} \tilde{g}''
     + \frac{1}{6}(y - \tilde{y})^3 \tilde{g}''' 
     + \frac{1}{24}(y - \tilde{y})^4 \tilde{g}^{IV} + O((y-\tilde{y})^{5})
   \right]
 \right\} \, dy
} \\[1ex] 
&= \REDUCE{
 \exp\{-n \tilde{g}\} \int_{\RR} \exp \left\{
   -\frac{n}{2}(y-\tilde{y})^{2} \tilde{g}''
   - \frac{n}{6}(y - \tilde{y})^3 \tilde{g}'''
   - \frac{n}{24}(y - \tilde{y})^4 \tilde{g}^{I V}
   + nO(y-\tilde{y})^{5}
 \right\} \, dy
} \\[2ex]
&=\frac{\exp\{-n \tilde{g}\} \sqrt{2 \pi}}{\sqrt{n \tilde{g}''}}
  \left\{
    1-\frac{1}{8} \frac{\tilde{g}^{IV}}{n(\tilde{g}'')^2}
     + \frac{5}{24n} \frac{(\tilde{g}''')^2}{(\tilde{g}'')^3}
     + O (n^{-2})
  \right\},
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]